# Read the last 20 bytes of a file

Tags: powershell, cmd

In an image files last 20 bytes, there is a checksum I need to retrieve. I have looked at the Get-Content command. Is there a way to reverse the reading so that it starts from the end of the file? If no, is there any other command that one can use to read the last 20 bytes of a file?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Get-Command`'s `-Tail` parameter, in combination with the `Byte` value for the `-Encoding` parameter:

```
$bytes = Get-Content myFile -Tail 20 -Encoding Byte
```

Contrary to the documentation, `-Tail` does not always act on lines.

Comment: Whereas [PSv6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) no more supports the `-Encoding Byte` but instead a `-AsByteStream` parameter